# HOW TO FILL THE NULL VALUES IN ROW?

Tags: mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9ZYP.png)I MADE A TABLE THEN ADDED A COLUMN TO IT NOW ALL THE COLUMN VALUES ARE NULL IN ALL ROWS

```
insert into students
 value  
('05','0005','fname','2000','m','fyit','1234567894','king5','332','500','624','650','CS','st','walk','email');
```

email is where the null value is supposed to be.

1)

```
create database siws;
use siws;
    create table students
        (
            student_id int(2) AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
            roll_no int(4),
            fullname char(10),
            dob int(4),
            gender char(1),
            class char(4),
            phone_no bigint(10),
            address varchar(20),
            ssc int(3),
            totssc int(3),
            hsc int(3),
            tothsc int(3),
            department char(2),
            caste char(4),
            travelling char(6)
```

);

2)

```
Insert into students
 value ('01','0001','aname','2000','m','syit','1234567890','king1','499','500','649','650','IT','open','bike');
 insert into students
 value ('02','0002','bname','2001','f','syit','1234567891','king2','497','500','639','650','CS','obc','cycle');
 insert into students
 value ('03','0003','cname','2002','m','fyit','1234567892','king3','437','500','629','650','IT','sc','car');
   insert into students
 value ('04','0004','dname','2002','f','syit','1234567893','king4','344','500','619','650','IT','open','plane');
   insert into students
 value ('05','0005','fname','2000','m','fyit','1234567894','king5','332','500','624','650','CS','st','walk');
```

3)

```
ALTER TABLE students
ADD Email varchar(255); //add column
```

sorry for the long codes im new here :)

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does the result currently look like? What should it look like? Edit the question accordingly

Comment: And note that `VALUE` is not the same as `VALUES`

Comment: Please add current and desired result to your question.

Comment: for add  the related  email value you should use UPDATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for add  a value to an existint row you need  update

```
     Update students
     set email = 'youreamil@yexample.com'
     where student_id =5
```